# White space issues with Automated DB configuration script

Tags: mysql, git, whitespace

I am trying to instigate some configuration control tools for our mysql databases. To start with we trained and installed GIT on all dev machines including DBA. I got a php script written that extract the definition of all db, all tables, functions,SP, views, and triggers and puts this is a directory structure.

My initial intention was to automate the scrip to run at fixed interval and recreate the directory based on the state of the db server at that time and have git commit the differences.

During testing, I realized that every time I run the script and do a git status, all the files are found to be modified. When I do a git diff I find that it is due to white spaces. Mostly at the end of line. During the previous commit they are trimmed off I think and when the configuration script runs they all come back therefore git thinks all files have change. So I can't do a simple git add .

The configuration management script itself runs on a windows machine but the databases it analyses can be on any platform.

The current git config is autocrlf true and core.white-space all off

What should the configuration be so that all these white spaces do not appear as a diff to git. Remember this is to be completely automated.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommending setting `core.autocrlf` to `false`. Having Git automatically try to convert line endings causes no end of problems.

Git does not automatically trim whitespace at the end of lines (unless you explicitly use `--whitespace=fix`) - from the information you have provided, it seems more likely that the problem is line ending handling.